# Read Integer values via Reader.(Sql-server)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

```
con.Open();
cmd = new SqlCommand("USE PRODUCTS SELECT BOUGHT FROM " +
                     DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text +
                     " WHERE ID = @ID", con);
cmd.Parameters.Add("ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = DropDownList2.SelectedIndex;
int i = cmd.ExecuteReader().GetInt32(0);
con.Close();
```

I can't read integer values with reader like this. I get runtime error System.InvalidOperationException. What is wrong with my code ? if you can't find the mistake, can you explain how can i read integer values with reader ? By the way this part of code gives the error:

```
int i = cmd.ExecuteReader().GetInt32(0);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialise a reader and then read it

```
using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
  while (rdr.Read()) // or just rdr.Read() if you know only one row is returned
  {
    int i = rdr.GetInt32(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
int x=0;
using (
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(strCon))
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql_string, connection);
    connection.Open();
    DataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            x = reader.GetInt32(0);
        }
    } 

    reader.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I have done to make things a lot easier on my end, since I mainly use SQL all over the place, is make some extensions.

eg

```
public static Int32 GetInt32(this SqlDataReader rdr, string column)
{
     return Convert.ToInt32(rdr[column]);
}
```